# How to change captions and dots?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, captions, punctuation, naming

I've received my master thesis from proofreader. I've received a lot of small things to fix but they're defined inside my document class which is `report`.

1. How to change caption name from "Table" to something else (in polish it's "Tablica" and I would like to change it into "Tabela".
2. How to change colon after number in caption into dot?
3. How to get rid of name Chapter - 
   when I put `\chapter{Method} \label{sec:Method}` in output I receive "Chapter 2" and below this "Method" (without any numbering).
4. How to put dot after every numbering in sections and subsection? (I have 2.1 and I would like to have 2.1. )

Comment: The `article` class doesn't define `\chapter`, so you would need a different class for that.

Comment: Oh, my. I wrote `article` - it should be `report`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Use

```
\renewcommand\tablename{Tablica}
```

This is defined in `article.cls` (see `classes` doc).

2) I suggest `caption` package. This can also answer quesiton 1.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{tablename=Talica,labelsep=period}
```

3) `article` does not provide `\chapter` :-)

For `report` and `book`, you can use some packages, like `sectsty`(simple) or `titlesec`(complex) to modify the layout. You'd better read the manual of theses packages.

And if you just want to get rid of the number and "Chapter", you may want to use

```
\chapter*{Title}
```

4) Use

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
```

and so on. And if you don't want to change the style how sections to be referred, you should also use `titlesec` package to modify the layout.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of questions ... :-)

1. Read the documentation of the package `caption`, it can define nearly everything.
2. see also package `caption`
3. depends on your documentclass, for KOMA-Script it is the prefix option
4. again, depends to your documentclass, KOMA-Script has an option for the dot, standard classes may be changed with `\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.}` And also redefine `\thesubsection`.

Answer (score 6):

For question 1:

`\usepackage[polish]{babel}` will switch "table" to "tablica" (and "chapter" to "rozdział" and so on). You can add `\addto\captionspolish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}}` to suit your preference. See also [this faq answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords).

Answer (score 2):

A "quick fix" for question 3 is

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: for the KOMA classes it is not needed, it is already the default

Comment: @Herbert: The OP uses the `report` class and may not want to switch to another class after the proofreading stage.

Comment: Ah yes, that's an argument!